# Logger.LogDebug vs Debug.WriteLine

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

I have this program

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace debuglogtest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
}
```

With this worker

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace debuglogtest
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("_logger.LogDebug");
            _logger.LogTrace("_logger.LogTrace");
            Debug.WriteLine("Debug.WriteLine");
        }
    }
}
```

and this configuration

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this in debug `dotnet run -c Debug` i get this in the console

> dbug: debuglogtest.Worker[0]
>        _logger.LogDebug

And this in DebugView
[image: DebugView of debug output]

This is expected, because as i understand it, when we compile our program, we get get debug logging. But when i compile this in release with `dotnet run -c Release` I still get this in the console

> dbug: debuglogtest.Worker[0]
>        _logger.LogDebug

But nothing in DebugView:

[image: DebugView of release output]

What i expect:

1. `_logger.LogDebug` is written both in console and in DebugView when compiling in debug, and no places when compiling in Release
2. `Debug.WriteLine` is written in DebugView when compiling in debug

What is actually happening:

1. `_logger.LogDebug` is only written to console, and not DebugView in debug mode

`Debug.WriteLine` is correctly written only when compiling in debug mode.

I thought that `LogDebug` was calling `Debug.WriteLine` under the hood, but maybe `Debug.WriteLine`and `Logger.LogDebug` is two different things? I surely looks like it. I think this is confusing because, we need to control Debug logging in two different places (when compiling and filtering). If i read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#debug it says that it calls the same `Debug.WriteLine`:

> The Debug provider writes log output by using the System.Diagnostics.Debug class. Calls to System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine write to the Debug provider.

Am I doing something wrong? I must be misunderstanding something. I want to be able to control `Logger.Debug` when compiling in Debug mode. Is that not possible?

**UPDATE**

If i check the source (even though it is kind of old (does anybody know an updated reference, please specify)): https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug/DebugLogger.debug.cs I can see that it defines `#define DEBUG`, and calls the `Debug.WriteLine`, but it doesn't add up in my head. It should be showing up in DebugView, but it doesn't in both debug and release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ILogger.LogDebug`, `ILogger.LogTrace` and so on is about [`LogLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) of message and not about where it is written and is basically equivalent to calling [`Log(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.log?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) with corresponding value of `logLevel` parameter. The write destination of log message is determined by which logger you are using (console, file, ETW, I'm sure that you can even create one which writes to the debug view see the [logging providers section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-providers) of docs). `LogLevel` allows you to filter which log level is actually written to the log destination and is regulated by appsettings and not directly by build configuration (though you can have different settings for different configurations).

Comment: It makes sense, but still, the `CreateDefaultHost` adds `.AddDebug()`. How does this fit into logging? Can't I use the `Logger` to write to a source that shows up in DebugView?

Comment: Actually it doesn't make sense in myhead. It adds the DebugProvider through `.AddDebug()` and it should show up in the DebugView. It shows up in the console, because `.AddConsole` is applied and with the `#define DEBUG` it actually should show up in release mode (in theory). Only if there is applied some kind of filtering (i guess there is). I think this is strange behaviour.

Comment: See the logging [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#debug) and [DebugLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.debug.debuglogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2), which is described as `A logger that writes messages in the debug output window only when a debugger is attached.`

Comment: I totally missed that line :) I have been through those docs a lot (see my update where i have added the same link). You are right. I dont know how can could have missed https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug/DebugLogger.cs#L44. Code never lies. Thanks! It all makes sense now. The DebugLogger activates writing to debug because of `#define DEBUG` in release mode, but what stops it, is line 44. Thanks again!

Comment: @mslot was glad to help!